# Separar por cantidad de posiciones en R

Tags: r, rstudio

Buenas noches espero que me puedan ayudar, tengo la siguiente cadena como ejemplo

```
00203049029103949503,
02030402029494029505,
00202029303940294930
```

y así sucesivamente, lo que necesito hacer es cada una de las filas almacenarlas en una tabla y separar por distintas posiciones, ejemplo.
codigo1(3), codigo2(3), tabla(4)

```
002         030          4902
020         304          0202
002         020          2930
```

Es decir crear la primera columna con tres datos, la segunda columna de largo 3 y así sucesivamente de distintos largos.
Me puedes ayudar por favor que estoy haciendo un trabajo en R y no se me ocurre.

Comment: Bienvenido Felipe Ferrada a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Answer (score 0):

Si esto parte de una lectura de un archivo en este formato, lo mejor es leerlo mediante: [`read.fwf()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.6.2/topics/read.fwf), por ejemplo:

```
read.fwf('archivo.txt', width = c(3,3,4,10))
```

Con `width = c(3,3,4,10)` defines secuencialmente los anchos de cada columna.

Si ya partes de un vector de caracteres, puedes usar esta función que básicamente adapte de la lógica de [`read.fwf()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.6.2/topics/read.fwf)

```
split_by_size <- function(x, widths) {

  drop <- (widths < 0L)
  cwidths <- cumsum(abs(widths))
  st <- c(1L, 1L + cwidths)
  first <- st[-length(st)][!drop]
  last <- cwidths[!drop]
  t(sapply(x, function(x) {substring(x, first, last)}, USE.NAMES = FALSE))

}

widths <- c(3,3,4,10)
x <- c('00203049029103949503', '02030402029494029505', '00202029303940294930')
split_by_size(x, widths)

     [,1]  [,2]  [,3]   [,4]        
[1,] "002" "030" "4902" "9103949503"
[2,] "020" "304" "0202" "9494029505"
[3,] "002" "020" "2930" "3940294930"
```